# Mixed mode debugging asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I have an asp.net application and can debug the application fine when I click F5 (Start Debugging), hits breakpoints, no problem. When I have a web app open and I try to attach to the w3wp.exe process, I get a message saying "Unable to attach to the process.  Mixed mode debugging is not supported on Windows 64-bit platforms."  Is there a way for me to attach to the process?

My asp.net application is .net 3.5, has a platform target specified as "Any CPU", and the Configuration set to debug.  I am developing on Win7 x64 bit system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS2008 doesn't support mixed mode debugging in 64 bit (it runs in 32 bit itself).

VS2010 does support this.

Try just selecting T-SQL, Managed, x64 when attaching the remote debugger.

See a possible solution here: ["Mixed mode debugging is not supported on Windows 64-bit platforms" when trying to attach to an ASP.NET process using Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708323/visual-studio-2008-with-asp-net-3-5-debuging-using-attach-to-process-is-not-worki)