# Unable to start debugging on the web server. Mixed mode debugging is not supported on Windows 64-bit platforms

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64

I have an asp.net 3.5 solution developed on a 32-bit machine under VS2008, everything was working ok until it got migrated to a 64-bit machine, on Win7 Professional. The project has 32-bit third party dlls as well, but they are working fine on a 64-bit Windows 2008 Server. Then when trying to debug the application using VS2008 I get this error message:

`Unable to start debugging on the web server. Mixed mode debugging is not supported on Windows 64-bit platforms.`

Which I don't really understand since I thought the CLR was processor agnostic, anyway what would be my options now? I have read about upgrading to .net 4.0, debugging from IIS, running on VS2010, CasiniDev, etc. The project was working fine and I only need a quick work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

CLR is processor agnostic it get converted to the correct version at run time; but the VS debugging plugins are not.

The 32bit/64bit-ness of the platform and what you're debugging has to match. If I remember correctly the bit-ness of the machine you're debugging from has to match too.

As it's a web application [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708323/mixed-mode-debugging-is-not-supported-on-windows-64-bit-platforms-when-trying) may allow you to work around it.

Comment: How can I debug it from IIS?